# Activator.CreateInstance with type name as string and including parameters

Tags: c#

I am working in .Net 3.5, looking at all the various constructors for Activator.CreateInstance.  I want to create an instance of a class, calling a particular constructor.  I do not have the class type, only its name.  I have the following, which works, but actually winds up calling the parameterless constructor first, then the one I want.  This is not  a terribly big deal, but the parameterless constructor calls a rather busy base constructor, and the constructor I want to call does, too.

In other words, given a type, calling CreateInstance with parameters is easy (only the last two lines below), but given only a type name, is there a better way than this?

```
ObjectHandle oh = Activator.CreateInstance( "MyDllName", "MyNS." + "MyClassName" );
object o = oh.Unwrap( );
object newObj = Activator.CreateInstance( o.GetType( ), new object[] { param1 } );
return ( IMyDesiredObject )newObject;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this overload of [CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyk798fw(VS.90).aspx).  It allows you to specify the type by name (string), as well as constructor arguments (6th parameter).

Comment: Thank you, Reed -- I saw that guy, but I didn't know what to do with the ActivationAttributes and SecurityInfo.  The docs didn't indicate (as with Binder and Culture) that they could be null, but it turns out that they can.  Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to get this to work was

```
  Type type = BuildManager.GetType(ServiceRef + ".SDK",false);

  Object nl = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

The `BuildManager.GetType` requires the fully qualified classname, in your case this is where you would pass "MyNS." + "MyClassName"

Comment: What is BuildManager? It must be from some library you use cause its not in .NET